# Can I embed an exe payload in a pdf, doc, ppt or any other file format?

Tags: security, pdf, ms-office, exe

Is there any way that I can embed a `.exe` file in a `.pdf`, `.doc`, `.xls`, or `.ppt` file in such a way that upon opening the containing file, the document processor will run the `.exe` automatically without the user intentionally executing it?

Comment: Is there any good reason to do that except for spreading malware?

Comment: That's a terrible idea.

Comment: I sincerely hope not!  --  But curiosity killed the cat; what legitimate reason would you have for wanting to do this, and how would you handle non-Microsoft systems (because if you have a legitimate reason, you will want your solution to be portable too).

Comment: If there is, I sure do hope that Microsoft fixes that vulnerability really quick (or http://77.fi/11f)

Comment: @Kimvais i hope this is a joke.  First of all Microsoft doesn't fix anything quickly, just look at the number of days IE has been left vulnerable to attack. 2nd of all this is Adobe which is even worse at fixing security flaws on time.

Comment: http://blog.didierstevens.com/2009/07/01/embedding-and-hiding-files-in-pdf-documents/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes,  this is totally possible and pretty easy to accomplish - so long as you have an active exploit in the PDF viewer.  Check out one of the many [Adobe Acrobat Exploits](https://www.rapid7.com/db/?q=adobe+acrobat&type=metasploit) in the Metasploit framework.   Next you can use a download+exec shellcode to download and execute your payload,  err I mean ".exe".

Comment: How do I do that? Do I download any software to attach the exe to pdf?

Comment: I want to learn how to do it **without** metasploit. Are there any resources that can help me understand the whole thing or just get me started?

Comment: @ayedaemon LOL, oh you sweet summer child.

Comment: @rook I agree! But I really want to learn what I don't know yet. Any leads/guidance will be helpful on this subject.

Comment: @ayedaemon it isn't possible because it would be a malware vector.

Comment: @rook Doing it with metasploit is also a malware... I just want to learn the same process manually instead of using metasploit process. I am not preparing for anything right now it's just for an understanding how such things are done and what sort of knowledge is required to do so.

Comment: @ayedaemon No, this feature will never exist without an exploit because it is a malware vector.  The only approach would be another exploit, and they are hard to come by these days.

Answer (score 3):

You can embed files with EXE or any other format. However, the ability to have the EXE run automatically depends on the viewer application and its security settings. This PDF feature has been exploited by many malware. So, there is no guarantee that it will work on all end-user systems. Be warned that if you make this feature a part of some commercial application, then security software will soon flag it as a malware, which can adversly affect your company's reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Besides using an exploit, you can just paste the file in using Acrobat Professional. Acrobat allows you to add arbitrary attachments these days.

If you make your PDF files with `pdflatex`, you can embed any file using the `embedfile` package. I use this frequently to add all kinds of files to PDF files. They show up as attachments.

```
\usepackage{embedfile}
\embedfile{my-wonderful-file.exe}
```

You can also use the Acrobat GUI to do it.

Answer (score -6):

In short, no. These file formats have no provision for embedding a Win32 PE executable inside of them.

For the Office files, you could use VBA to write a script that runs when the document is opened.

Comment: can you suggest any link that shows some example of it.
It will very much helpful for me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications

Comment: This is pretty easy to do with metasploit.